# list of Connected Devices on the Wifi Hotspot

Tags: java, android, nokia, arp, hotspot

i have a [nokia device](https://www.nokia.com/phones/en_int) with Android 11 . this device doesn't show Connected Devices CURRENTLY connected to the Wifi Hotspot. IOT Development boards like Arduino  or [ESP32](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/socs/esp32) etc... connected to the device's hotspot becomes useless as their respective android apps require their IP addresses to monitor them. Android 11 devices from other manufacturers readily show the list (name, ip & mac addresses) of devices connected to their hotspot right within the Settings.

i tried reading the file "/proc/net/arp". permission was denied.
i tried executing "ip neigh show" returned null.
i tried android.net.wifi.* methods and classes nothing leads to an instance of currently active Wifi Hotspot or SoftApInfo or DhcpInfo or TeatheredHotspot.
any piece of source code on [google source](https://android.googlesource.com) or [android source](https://cs.android.com/) is either deprecated or not present at all in newer android sdk.

Turns out, Android 10 & above has restricred access to the "[/proc/net](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#proc-net-filesystem)" file.

even the [alternatives](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager) [provided](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager) there don't work...

None of the above workarounds work.
please help...